# Animation started at specyfic moment

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

How to make, that animation starts from the moment of moving to specific anchor?

For example i have a three anchor at page(Home,services and Contact).
Im using "Typing" animation.

```
@keyframes type{ 
  from { width: 0; } 
} 

@keyframes type2{
  0%{width: 0;}
  50%{width: 0;}
  100%{ width: 100; } 
} 

@keyframes blink{
  to{opacity: .0;}
}
```

At the page i have included a jquery.

And now i dont know how to make, that animation will starts from the moment of moving to specific anchor...

Comment: It sounds like you need to make use of `:hover`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: I not mean about "hover". I mean about a "anchor" and "anmiation". For example u have three anchor on site(home, services and contact). Assuming that site is onepage, animation start before user will coming to specyfic content on my site(animation will be end before he will come).

Comment: well i read the question 3 times and didn't understand :s can you elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you want to start a CSS Animation when an element is in the viewport, right?

You need to detect if an element is inside the viewport with javascript, and then add a class which plays your animation. There are many tutorials for that on the web for that, but here's a fiddle with 3 boxes, that animate as you scroll and see them [( found here )](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/tw6g2oeu/7/)

```js
// Plugin @RokoCB :: Return the visible amount of px
// of any element currently in viewport.
// stackoverflow.com/questions/24768795/
;(function($, win) {
  $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
     return this.each(function(i,el){
       function visPx(){
         var H = $(this).height(),
             r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
         return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t>0? H-t : (b<H?b:H)));  
       } visPx();
       $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
     });
  };
}(jQuery, window));



$(".box").inViewport(function(px){
    if(px) $(this).addClass("triggeredCSS3") ;
});
```

```css
.box{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin:500px 50px;
    background:red;
    transition: 1.5s;
}

.rotate.triggeredCSS3    {transform : rotate(360deg); }
.scale.triggeredCSS3     {transform : scale(1.6); }
.translate.triggeredCSS3 {transform : translate3d(400px,0,0); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box rotate"></div>
<div class="box scale"></div>
<div class="box translate"></div>
```

Comment: U are my god ! Thank u very much bro !